# Clarifications images inside a table-cell

Tags: html, css

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/CDUBv/ 
So, there are two problems:

1. How to display images in the same line without specifying the width of the table-cell? I also tried with `display: inline`, but the second image goes newline.
2. In the second table-cell text is not aligned correctly, because the text starts from the end of the first image, such as align it properly in the first line?

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: is this what you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/CDUBv/1/?

Comment: don't set width="100%" on #t2

Comment: I would like this: http://oi43.tinypic.com/2en5hxy.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my edits: http://jsfiddle.net/dinhyen/CDUBv/4/

1. This makes the images inline with `display: inline` and also creates a wrapper with `white-space: no-wrap` so that they stay adjacent.
2. Use a `vertical-align: top` to position the text in the second cell.

Comment: You're right, `display: inline` would be redundant for images. More generally it's probably better to use `display: inline-block`. http://jsfiddle.net/dinhyen/CDUBv/9/